# Compile opencore-amr for iOS，but always "configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: c++, ios, configure

I just got the source code from here

https://github.com/feuvan/opencore-amr-iOS

but when I run the .sh file, it always be "configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables"

```
-----------------------------------
.......
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /opt/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /opt/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/jun/Downloads/opencore-amr-iOS-master':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
-----------------------------------
```

OSX 10.9.4, xcode 6.1 , command line tools

who can help ?

Comment: This should be your hint: `checking whether the C++ compiler works... no`. Do you have a working compiler? Test with a small hello world program, if you are able to build and create executable.

Comment: @rockoder: xcode contains clang as default, and I've already installed 'command line tools'. I need to install another compiler? like gcc or g++ ?